# Download all files matching a mask from a remote FTP directory tree to the same local folder

Tags: download, ftp, wget

I am trying to download a file with name ending with `*.csv`.

The problem is complicated by the fact that this `*.csv` contains in directory of unknown name:

E.g. Sometimes it would be

```
2015/Date 29:10:20:10/One.csv
```

or

```
2015/Date 27:10:21:10/Two.csv
```

How do I use Wget or *anything* (in Linux) that does wildcard directory matching, as well as wildcard file matching?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know, if any FTP tool supports, what you need.

It's easy though to script this with any scripting language you like.

For an example of such PowerShell script, see [WinSCP example for downloading all files from FTP/SFTP to the same local folder](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_download_files_to_same_folder).

---

Alternatively, you can download the file with its remote directory structure and flatten it locally.

E.g. using [WinSCP for download](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation):

```
@echo off
set TMPPATH=%temp%\csvtmp
mkdir "%TMPPATH%"
winscp.com /command ^
    "open ftp://user:password@example.com/" ^
    "get ""/root/"" -filemask=*.csv ""%TMPPATH%""" ^
    "exit"
for /r "%TMPPATH%" %%f in ("*.*") do move "%%f" "c:\targetpath\"
rd /s /q "%TMPPATH%"
```

---

*This is for Windows. Only now I've noticed that you ask for Linux solution, sorry. Leaving my answer here anyway, in case it helps someone else.*

Answer (score 0):

WinSCP would solve your problem on Windows. This tool has an ability to download files by mask https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_transfer_custom